# Sharepoint 2010 can't find domain users when granting permissions

Tags: authentication, permissions, people-picker

I'm trying to grant permissions to other people to view a SharePoint site but when granting permissions it uses "Check Names" and claims any user or group that is part of a domain does not exist. It does this if I try granting permissions to the team site or in central admin BUT if I try to add someone to Farm Administrators in Central admin then all of the sudden it can find all domain users.

Why is it finding domain users in that one context but not others? It is supposed to be using NTLM authentication and has Windows configured as the authentication provider (And IIS is configured to use NTLM). What's even more strange is I enabled Anonymous Access for the team site which I thought would allow anyone to view it but others say they can't access it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the problem was caused by the IIS app that the site collection was running under had a local user account as its identity and that user didn't have access to AD. I changed the identity to a domain user in IIS Manager and restarted the web app and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

First, did you set up User Profile Synchronization to retrieve all users from AD?

Comment: That is not what User Profile Synchronization is for. I did not provision user profiles at all because I am not using these features.

Answer (score 0):

You should sync using User Profile Synchronization Service.

See it: http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx